# UITableViewCell images only show after TableView has been scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using SDWebImage to set profile images for UITableViewCell's however after the Request is made the Images only are displayed after the TableView is scrolled. However the Usernames and other info are displayed. Here is how I am attempting to set the images:

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:totalArray[@"profile_picture"] placeholderImage:nil options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
```

My REST Request works perfectly and the JSON returns and saves within the NSDictionary correctly.

Comment: show some other code where u r getting images

Comment: have you called [tableView reloadData] ?

Comment: `UITableViewCell` is only created when it is visible i.e when scrolled. Ideally this is a good behaviour since only those images which are visible is downloaded. If you set a breakpoint you can see that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only called for visible cells, as soon as you scroll it is invoked again to get a new cell. This is how a `UITableView` works